# Homepage background image remains

Tags: css, background-image

I am coding my website on `CargoCollective`. I wanted the home page to have a different background image than the rest, to be precise I wanted it to have a full-scale GIF, while the other pages should only have a background color. I did find the CSS code for the full-scale background, but the problem is that when I go first to the homepage and then to the other pages through the links of the sidebar, the background image remains, instead of turning to `background-color`. The weird fact is that whenever I refresh the pages or directly go to them (without passing from the homepage), that background image doesn't show up and it is the color I chose. What is the problem?

```
body { 
    background-color:#ffe0e0!important; 
    color: #f54a63; 
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    text-align: left; 
    line-height: 2; 
    position: relative; 
    top: -40px; 
    width: 100%; 
} 

body.home { 
    background: url(payload498.cargocollective.com/1/22/724019/12271389/gif1‌​4.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover; 
} 

body.pages { 
    background-color: #ffe0e0!important;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? Relevant styles, html or a URL to show the problem?

Comment: My css looks like that 'body {
 background-color:#ffe0e0!important;
 color: #f54a63;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
 line-height: 2;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    width: 100%;
  
  
  
}
body.home{ 
  background: url(http://payload498.cargocollective.com/1/22/724019/12271389/gif14.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
body.pages { 
  background-color: #ffe0e0!important;}'

Comment: Then I use for each pages and the home page, <body class="home/pages">some content</body>.   
You can see the website here, http://cargocollective.com/lydiakaragiannaki. It is really weird, like the background image stucks and I need to refresh the pages to get it out.

Comment: it's because you have `class="home"` still on the body tag when you're navigating pages and when you refresh the page the body tag's `class="main open"`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply add the code inline on your home page:

```
<body style="url(background:url(myGif.gif) no-repeat 0 0;background-size: cover;"/>
```

A second way is to overwrite the css with javascript/jQuery when you load your home page:

```
$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(myGif.gif)', 'background-size':'cover'});
```

A third way is to simply add a full screen div with the background attached:

```css
html,body{height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
body{
  background:#000;
}
#coverDiv{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:url(https://media.giphy.com/media/9fbYYzdf6BbQA/giphy.gif);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="coverDiv">
 This div goes on my home page only.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the first version doesn't work, the third applies only to the box of the post and not the whole page, as for the second, I still have to educate myself how to use jQuery!

Comment: There was a slight error with my code in the first one. Try it now! You only need to apply the style attribute to the body tag on your home page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this class to your style sheet. It will cover the case where you're navigating from your home page to another page. The rule for css is that the most specific class/selector wins in priority, the problem you were having is that body is more generic than body.home also it needs to be the same attribute, so background instead of background-color.

```
body.home.open {
    background: #ffe0e0;
    color: #f54a63;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 2;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```